# How does this work str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '')?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

**energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r'(.*)', '')**

I know this will remove parenthesis but here what exactly does this **(r'(.*)', '')**  do ..can you pls explain in detail ?

Comment: This is a regular expression. It is a way to describe a string pattern in a way that a programming language can understand.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/1ILwiN/1